# Converting an equation into R code

Tags: r

I have a very long expression that I want to convert into R code. Here is an example showing what the expression looks like/how it is written:

```
(a exp(-a t) t^4)/(24 (a-b) (a-c) (a-d))
```

In order to be understandable by R, the multiplication sign `*` should be added between the variables, brackets etc. Is there a way to do this automatically rather than inserting it manually?
The expression should look like this:

```
(a *exp(-a*t) *t^4)/(24* (a-b)* (a-c)* (a-d))
```

Comment: How your expression is stored?

Comment: I stored it as a CDF file and then copied the text into R studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input is of the form shown then it would be sufficient to replace each space with a * using `gsub` like this:

```
expr <- "(a exp(-a t) t^4)/(24 (a-b) (a-c) (a-d))"
gsub(" +", "*", expr)
## [1] "(a*exp(-a*t)*t^4)/(24*(a-b)*(a-c)*(a-d))"
```

Comment: Yop thats absolutely a good idea. Also, I can do the replacement using Notepad++ which is really handy! Thank you.